# Firebase Firestore get() not working

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

The part it doesn't like is the get() method in ngOnInit().
Is says, **"[ts] Property 'get' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreDocument<{}>'."**

I looked here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data
and it shows to use get() method for a single doc, but it just doesn't like that method for me?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { User } from './user';

@Component({
   selector: 'user-form',
   templateUrl: 'user-form.component.html'
})
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {
form: FormGroup;
title: string;
user = new User();
id;
userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;
singleUser: Observable<User>;      

constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private afs: AngularFirestore, private _router: Router, private _route: ActivatedRoute) {

    //
    this.form = fb.group({
        //username: ['', Validators.required],
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        title: ['', Validators.required]
    })



}

ngOnInit() {
    this.title = "Update User";

    this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params["id"];
    });

    if(!this.id) {
        console.log("New User");
    } 
    else {


        this.afs.collection("users").doc(this.id)
        .get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            } else {
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });


    }

}

//
submit() {
    console.log(this.user.title + " - " + this.user.email);

    if (this.id) {   
        this.afs.doc('users/' + this.id).update({
            title: this.user.title, 
            email: this.user.email  
        });   ;                                                       
    }
    else{            
        this.afs.collection('users').add({
            name: this.user.title,  
            email: this.user.email  
        });                         
    }

    this._router.navigate(['']);
}
```

}

Comment: If you check the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) more detail, you can find it returns `firebase.firestore.DocumentReference`, but you are using `angularfire2` now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Actually, `AngularFirestoreDocument<{}>` doesn't have `get` property,
>   use `AngularFirestoreDocument<{}>.ref` instead:

```
this.afs.collection("users")
            .doc(this.id)
            .ref
            .get().then(function(doc) {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
                } else {
                    console.log("No such document!");
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting document:", error);
            });
```

Comment: well you are correct, but I don't see that anywhere in the literature? Should I have done something different?

Comment: Can you see my changes? just added `doc('xxxId').ref.get()`.

Comment: I mean I don't see it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data - how did you know that? And what should I have done differently so not to have to use the .ref?

Comment: Exactly, the document guides all as a `Javascript SDK`, but you are using `angularfire2` which was customized for `angular` projects.

Comment: so you are using `doc()` method of `AngularFirestore`, not `firebase.firestore.doc()`.

Comment: do you have a link to the AngularFirestore documentation?

Comment: This is [AngularFirestore official guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md) what you are looking for.

Comment: wow, that's some bad doc writing if I had to get to here to find out. wasted some good time scratching my head and poking around

Answer (score -2):

You're using Angular Fire, so the syntax is the following:

```
this.afs.collection("users").doc(this.id).valueChanges(user => {
     console.log(user);
});
```

Read the documentation here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2