# Angular 5 - Observables: Can't access the value of a document using Firestore

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services

I can't get the value of a document when I trie to get it using its id, when I displays the variable in the console it display

> Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}

this the definition of my function in my service

```
getDataDetails(id: any) {
    this.dataDocumment = this.afs.doc('economie/' + id);
    return this.dataDocumment.valueChanges();;
  }
```

this is my template

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="header text-center">
          <h3 class="title">{{dataD.adresse | async | json}}</h3>
          <p class="category">Ensemble d'informations sur les communes prioritaires ou intervient CPDEP</p>
      </div>
      <div class="places-sweet-alerts">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">

                  <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header card-header-icon" data-background-color="red">
                          <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-content">
                          <h4 class="card-title">Présentations des communes</h4>
                          <div class="toolbar">



                                  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
                                  <div class="col-lg-8">
                                      <div class="card">
                                          <div class="card-header card-header-danger" data-background-color="red">
                                              <h4 class="card-title">Circonscription de </h4>
                                              <p class="category">Département du </p>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="card-content">
                                              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                                  <li class="list-group-item">Arrondissement : </li>
                                                  <li class="list-group-item">Nombre de sections communales : </li>
                                                  <li class="list-group-item">Organisation : </li>
                                                  <li class="list-group-item">Superficie : </li>
                                                  <li class="list-group-item">Population : </li>
                                                  <li class="list-group-item">Economie : </li>
                                                  <li class="list-group-item">Nombre de centres de vote : </li>
                                                  <li class="list-group-item">Nombre de bureaux de vote : </li>
                                                  <li class="list-group-item">Nombre d'électeur : </li>

                                              </ul>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>

                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
                              

                          </div>

                      </div>
                      <!-- end content-->
                  </div>
                  <!--  end card  -->
              </div>
              <!-- end col-md-12 -->
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this my my component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EconomieService } from '../../services/economie.service';
import { Router, Params, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-economie-detail',
  templateUrl: './economie-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./economie-detail.component.scss']
})
export class EconomieDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  id : string ;
  dataD : any;
  constructor(private eco: EconomieService,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.dataD = this.eco.getDataDetails(this.id);
  }
}
```

Any idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: You need to use `.subscribe` to get the data out of an observable when it emits.

Comment: maybe this thread can help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821449/10109757)

Comment: @ahsan, looks like it's for older version as it is using `.then` to unwrap the value. The current version of AngularFire2 returns an `Observable`. Here's using `valueChanges()` anyway.

Comment: Your Component code is still missing.

Comment: `dataD.adresse | async | json` should be `dataD | async | json` And BTW, this is just to check the value that this Observable will resolve to.

Try doing this:  `(dataD | async)?.adresse`

Comment: I did it displays null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [AngularFire2 documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges), Stream Document Data using `valueChanges()` returns an Observable which needs to be unwrapped to get the actual data.

You'll have to `subscribe` to it to get the value.

You might also want to consider simply using an `async` pipe so as to not `unsubscribe` from the subscription to avoid any memory leaks.

So, considering this function is exposed from a service named `DataService`, wherever you're using this function, just do this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  data;
  data$;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getDataDetails('someId').subscribe(data => console.log(data));

    // OR
    this.data$ = this.dataService.getDataDetails('someId');

  }

}
```

And then, in your template:

```
{{ data$ | async | json }}
```

This will unwrap the Observable when being passed through the `async` pipe. Whatever is the output of the `async` pipe will be passed through the `json` pipe which will `stringify` the JSON Object into string. And that's what will get printed on to the string. Hope it makes sense now.

**For your Specific Use Case**

Use this:

```
{{ (dataD | async)?.adresse }}
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firebase-eg) if that helps. I'm pretty sure that should make it work. Here's the sort of data that I have in the Cloud Firestore.

[image]

Comment: I folowed your instruction now it display the value of my document in the console but the binding return display null in my template

Comment: Please post a minimal code sample for your Component TypeScript class and your Template

Comment: Just be sure to either use just `data` or `data$`. If you're using just `data` in your template, use it like `{{ data | json }}`. If you're using `data$` use it like `{{ data$ | async | json }}`

Comment: it doesn't work for my case, now  it gave me this error InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe after your last recommendations

Comment: That would only make sense if `dataD` was not an observable but an object. In that case just use `{{ dataD | json }}` to see what prints to the DOM.